# Swift - viewDidLoad getting called when app moves to the background

Tags: swift

I'm trying to solve a crash that happens when a method gets called inside viewDidLoad when the app moves to the background. If I move the method into viewDidAppear the crash doesn't repro anymore.

But I'm wondering, is it expected that viewDidLoad gets called when the app moves to the background?

Comment: that's not expected. can you post the call stack?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the details of the crash and the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not expected for this to happen.

Step 1

- Check your AppDelegate class inside AppDelegate.swift
- Find the applicationDidEnterBackground() method.
- If there's anything in there calling the viewDidLoad() method in your ViewController, you've found the issue.

Step 2

- Run your app
- Put a breakpoint inside your viewDidLoad() method
- Put your app into the background
- Did the breakpoint get hit?
- Click the tiny button in the bottom middle area, a small rectangle with an upwards pointing arrow above it
- This will take you to the last place this was called. And you will (hopefully) find the issue.

Step 3

- I have no other ideas. Some more information would be super helpful.